# Source of long running find process on server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, find

I'm wondering where a long running `find` process on my ubuntu linux server (14.04 LTS) came from and what the meaning of it is. Here is the output of ps:

```
16915 ?        SN    32:41 /usr/bin/find /tmp /var/tmp -type f -exec head -n 1 {} ;
```

According to `top` this causes quite some CPU load. As far as I understand it, it checks the first line of every file in `/var/tmp` and `/tmp` with `head` - so it does nothing besides causing load?

Can anybody tell me what this process is supposed to do and where it might come from? And, if not needed, how I can get rid of it? I killed it once, but it reappeared.

EDIT: The server is used as a web server with PHP, MySQL, Varnish - if you need to know more about the installed software, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try finding the Parent of the process?

Comment: Thanks! Stupid me, this was an easy one. Parent seems to be `/usr/sbin/chkrootkit -q` - so I guess, everything is fine then. Will add the details as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to "embedded" I checked the parent of the process via

`cat /proc/[PID]/status | grep PPid`

and it turns out that its parent was

`/bin/sh /usr/sbin/chkrootkit -q`

So everything seems fine.

Comment: See also `pstree` and `ps auxfw` for showing visual process tree with parent/child relations.